# what is the difference between using (@Inject(Http) http: Http) or not

Tags: typescript, angular

After this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350130/error-using-http-json-angularjs-2/35350172?noredirect=1#35350547), I have new a question. What is the difference between these two ways?

This was my initial code:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({

viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
..//

constructor(http: Http){
..//
```

but while doing tests, They provided with codes to find the error:

```
import { Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
//above code should be at start.

constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http) {
```

I think it works the same either way, someone could tell me, what is the difference, or just the first one is like the second but `@Inject` is implicit or something similar.Sorry for my English.

Comment: good question but possible duplicate of my question's third part http://stackoverflow.com/q/35230878/5043867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `@Inject` decorator is used to ask for a dependency of a certain type. A string is also supported at this level.

If you already have a decorator of the class like `Component` or `Injectable` and you specify a type in TypeScript for the parameter (your case), using this other decorator isn't necessary because the resolution will be by class automatically. If you don't provide a type, the `@Inject` decorator will be useful...

Another use case. If you want to use **ngUpgrade** (hybrid Angular1 / Angular2 applications), factories of Angular1 are registered by name only and you can't resolve them by class. So using `@Inject` is necessary here. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview. It's written in TypeScript but without annotation but can be adapted ;)

You could also have a look at this link:

- Injecting services in services in Angular 2 by Pascal Precht - http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Comment: sorry but i am still confused is it necessary to provide at least one either `@component` or `@injectable` for angular2 ?

Comment: To be able to inject something, you need a decorator at the level of the class. When the class is instantiated, the decorator will intercept the call and provide the excepted parameters using the current injector. @Inject allows to define more hints about what to inject when object types don't apply or if there is no type.

Comment: Interesting thing is that `Component({ ... })...` chain and `Inject` function  are used in plunker example, instead of a real class and `@Component` and `@Inject` decorators. Was it done just to match ES5-ish style of code (doesn't seem appropriate because this is still TypeScript), or is there a necessity to do this here?

Comment: Here there is no necessity to do that. With TypeScript, I see one use case (perhaps there are other) where @Inject is useful: to use forwardRef.