# Angular 2 Global Constants Provider Injector Method

Tags: angular

I have a global constants like root directory that I want every component to have access to. In another stackoverflow question the answer was to create a constants class and import that to every component.

Is there a way to bootstrap a constants class so that every component in the app has access to it without any additional importing?

I have this so far but it is not working, how do I boostrap the constants class and then access then in my components?

`constants.ts`

```
export class Constants{
  root_dir: string;

  constructor(){
      this.root_dir = 'http://google.com/'
    }
  }
```

`main.ts`

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {Constants} from './constants'

bootstrap([
  provide(Constants, {useClass: Constants})
]);
```

`random.component.ts`

```
import {Component, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `{{test}}`
})

export class RandomComponent{
    test: string;

    constructor(){
        this.test = injector.get(Constants.root_dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right there. You just have to pass `Constants` through the constructor : `constructor(constants: Constants) {}` (you'll have to import it anyway or TS will complain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- All components using the Constants class will need to import your constants file.
- In order to use the Constants class you need to inject it into the constructor of any consuming components, removing the injector.get() function from random.component.ts like so:

```js
export class App {
  constructor(constants: Constants) {
    this.url = constants.root_dir;
  }
}
```

You may also decorate your constant class as an `@Injectable` and `@Inject` it into the constructor of your component.

[Here is a working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/1OHKlQVnYz6MOHoJqrvm?p=preview)

It is beneficial to bootstrap the shared constants at the app level so that only one instance of the class is created and shared among all components.

Comment: Is there any benefit to injecting it into the constructor? Is that what makes it so only on instance is created?

Comment: DI makes it easy to configure and therefore easy to test. Otherwise it's hardcoded and testing can become quite cumbersome.

Comment: @ClickThisNick it is the recommended pattern to get maximum DI flexibility for testing, ngUpgrade and use of forwardRef, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351649/1774183

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Component,bind,provide} from 'angular2/core';

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/form';
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input,ViewChild,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Constants} from 'src/constants'
import {ViewChild, Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `{{test}}`,
})


export class App {
    test: string;

    constructor(cs:Constants){
        this.test = cs.root_dir;
    }
}

bootstrap(App, [Constants]);
```

***[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/x6LlAB7OG7BOa9Hhn8TS?p=preview)***

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import { Constants } from './constants'

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `  
                    Constants: <strong>{{ urlTemplate }}</strong>

              `
    providers:[Constants]

})

export class AppComponent{

  constructor(constants: Constants){
    this.urlTemplate = constants.root_dir;
  }

}
```

You can use adding `Constants` in `providers:[Constants]`

---

The decorator @Injectable It is not necessary in this case, but Google recommends always use You can see here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#why-injectable-

---

```
/*
We recommend adding @Injectable() to every service class, even those that don't have dependencies and, therefore, do not technically require it. Here's why:
Future proofing: No need to remember @Injectable when we add a dependency later.
Consistency: All services follow the same rules, and we don't have to wonder why a decorator is missing
*/

//@Injectable() 
export class Constants{
  root_dir: string;

  constructor(){
      this.root_dir = 'http://google.com/'
    }
  }
```

### <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/axbd5Jtt17soLAcBurja?p=preview)</kbd>

---

About @Inject used, you can read something here:
[what is the difference between using (@Inject(Http) http: Http) or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351212/what-is-the-difference-between-using-injecthttp-http-http-or-not)

---

Now if you want this globally can add in `bootstrap`

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app';
import { Constants } from './constants';


bootstrap(AppComponent, Constants)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

---

```
//import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core'

//@Injectable()
export class Constants{
root_dir: string;

  constructor(){
      this.root_dir = 'http://google.com/'
    }
  }
```

---

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core'
import { Constants } from './constants';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `  
                    Constants: <strong>{{ urlTemplate }}</strong>

              `

})


export class AppComponent{

  constructor(@Inject (Constants) constants: Constants){
    this.urlTemplate = constants.root_dir;
  }

}
```

### <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvuUn3wx6qbVrBw7gKFU?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I'm new to Angular2 is not if the above is the best way to get what you want, I hope it will help