# How to design common methods in Angular 5

Tags: angular, http

Working on my first Angular app.

All of my services will talk to a web service on the same server. I want each of the services to use common code to perform this communication to allow the services to communicate on the business logic. For instance, I want to code the server name once.

The way I've done this on other platforms is to create a static class with those methods on it and then call those methods from my services. How do I achieve this with Angular 5, as I'm only aware of templates, components, and services?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: For DI usage of constants, see [Angular 2 Global Constants Provider Injector Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822486/angular-2-global-constants-provider-injector-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new object called web.ts. Here's the code:

```
@Injectable()
export class Web {
  headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {'access-control-allow-origin':'*'}
  );

  rootUrl = "http://localhost:8093/";

}
```

and then added to my app.module.ts as a provider:

```
  providers: [Web],
```

Then I simply injected it into my clients like a service:

```
  constructor(private web: Web) {}
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: There already is an 'environment' file that can be replaced at build with a different one. Why not use that? I guess you don't want the `rootUrl` to be `localhost` on a production environment...

Answer (score 4):

A pretty common approach is to have a file named something like `config.ts` with an object APP_CONFIG that stores any properties you might need. Then you can simply import the config object and use the desired properties.

**UPDATE**

You can also inject strings and objects into services with @Inject decorator (you also have to provide them first):

Your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(@Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) { // ... }
}
```

Your appConfig.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {API_BASE_URL} from 'some/path';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: API_BASE_URL,
            useValue: 'https://example.com'
        }
    ]
})

export class AppConfigModule {
}
```

This way you'll be able to use DI to mock this dependency for testing purposes.

Comment: I felt that your answer was insufficient, so I created one of my own that provided all of it. I still upvoted yours.

Comment: @Thorn, I updated my answer with another way of using shared constants, check it out

Answer (score 2):

what I did for this in my previous project was as follows. I created a config.ts file with the following content.

**config.ts**

```
export const config = Object.freeze({
    server: 'http://localhost/',
    folder: 'angular5/'
});
```

Then I imported this file into the services that made the Http call & used it as follows:

```
import { config } from './../shared/config/config';

private server = config.server + config.folder;
private contactUsURL = this.server + '/api/contact-us';
```

You may please use this to complete up the actual URL for Http calls.I hope, by this way you can create & use common constants in your project with ease.

Answer (score 1):

**ng generate class Constants**

your class should look like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Constants {

  public static readonly API_URL = 'api';

  static Role = class {
    public static readonly ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
  };
}
```

use in component:

```
import {Constants} from '../constants';

...

console.log(Constants.Role.ADMIN);
console.log(Constants.API_URL);
```